# Magento code in gitignore and need to update version

Tags: git, magento, version-control, gitignore

We are working on Magento2 project, versioning is done through GIT, where all vendor/lib files are put in gitignore.

As per our deployment structure, we have multiple env such as - DEV/SIT/UAT/PROD, all managed through git branches.

Now, project needs to update Magento2 version, which will involve update of native code files in vendor/lib etc.

How can this be managed so that we can push in GIT, and propagate these changes on other enviornments.

Comment: Hi @huzefam  do you have following entry /vendor in you .gitignor file?

Comment: yes @Muk that is correct

Comment: remove / from in front of vendor and try. Which update method are you trying?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use composer to manage your Magento project version if you are not committing the vendor directory to git. [The devdocs go into detail on how to update Magento 2](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/comp-mgr/cli/cli-upgrade.html).

You won't be able to manage this solely through git if you are not committing the vendor or lib directory. You'll have to run the composer commands as part of your deployment process to the environments.

From the documentation:

To pull in the new version:

`composer require magento/product-community-edition <version-number> --no-update`

`composer update`

And run the update scripts:
`php bin/magento setup:upgrade`

You'll have to clear the cache and generated directories as well.